# which method in pandas.io.sql is equivalent to mysqlDB fetchone()

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any method equivalent in `pandas.io.sql` equivalent to mysqldb's `fetchone`? something like this:

```
qry="select ID from reports.REPORTS_INFO where
REPORT_NAME='"+rptDisplayName+"'"

psql.read_sql(qry, con=db)
reportId = psql.fetchone()
```

Comment: it would be helpful if u explained what the fetchone function does

Comment: This method retrieves the next row of a query result set and returns a single sequence, or None if no more rows are available. By default, the returned tuple consists of data returned by the MySQL server, converted to Python objects.

Answer (score 0):

`read_sql` from `pandas.io.sql` returns the data as dataframe which is the result of your entire query, there is no need to fetch results.

```
# data is a dataframe with the result from the query
data = psql.read_sql(qry, con=db)
```